# Avoid Duplicates on SQL JOIN

Tags: sql

I have two tables as below

```
Table A
ID   ID_Name    Amount
------------------------
1    ABC        200
2    XYZ        300

Table B
ID    Role    Name 
------------------
1     Plumber   John
1     Estimator  Redmond
```

I want to join both tables and I need the result as below

```
ID ID_Name  Plumber Estimator   Amount
--------------------------------------
1   ABC     John      Redmond   200
```

SQL I am using to JOIN

````
Select A.ID, A.ID_Name

CASE WHEN B.Role='Plumber' THEN B.Name END AS Plumber,
CASE WHEN B.Role='Estimator' THEN B.Name END AS Estimator,
A.Amount
FROM A A
INNER JOIN B B ON A.ID=B.ID

```
How I can achieve this, when am trying to join I am getting two lines for the same ID and if do group by amount is 400
````

Comment: please post the SQL you're using to join

Comment: how can we possibly tell you what is wrong if you don't post your code?

Answer (score 5):

You should join the tableb two time one for Plumber and one for estimator

```
select a.ID,  a.ID_Name, b1.name plumber, b2.name estimator, a.amount
from tableA a
inner join tableb b1 on a.id = b1.id and b1.role ='Plumber'
inner join tableb b2 on a.id = b2.id and b2.role ='Estimator'
```

if you have duplicated  row the you should use distinct

```
select distinct  a.ID,  a.ID_Name, b1.name plumber, b2.name estimator, a.amount
from tableA a
inner join tableb b1 on a.id = b1.id and b1.role ='Plumber'
inner join tableb b2 on a.id = b2.id and b2.role ='Estimator'
```

Comment: I am getting  two lines for the same ID if DO this

Comment: You shouldn't need `DISTINCT`, right? Unless there's some bigger data/normalization issue...

Comment: @Zack  correct  .. answer  updated ..  with both the solution  .. anyway if the data sample is coherent the distinct clause is not needed

Answer (score 0):

While @scaisEdge will work for the given scenario, I would say you have to reconsider the schema of Table B. The result you are expecting is dynamic. With the query given above for now you are going doing roles in a line. What will happen if another new role gets introduced?

If Plumber and Estimator are mandated entities for a given Id, instead of having just TableB.Role may be redesign like TableB.Plumber, TableB.Estimator.

Comment: I just need those two roles for this SQL